# How can I download images without holding up everything else?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I'm making an app that allows you to browse through pictures from a website.  I'm currently downloading the images using:

```
 UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

which works great, but can be time consuming.  I start off by downloading 20 images, but I can't do anything until after the 30 or so seconds it takes to download them all.

This one time wait isn't all that bad, but if I want to download the 21st-40th images, I would have to wait another 30 seconds.

Basically, is there a way I can download these images one at a time without holding up any of my animations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, put the download task in a thread, and use a callback to let your program know when each image is finished.  Then you can draw your images as they finish loading, and not hold up the rest of the app.  [This link](http://kdl.nobugware.com/post/2008/12/22/nsthread-iphone-template/) has a template that you can use as an example.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
- (void)downloadWorker:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool  = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL             *url   = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData            *data  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage           *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageLoaded:) 
                           withObject:image
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
    [image release];
    [pool drain];
}

- (void)downloadImageOnThread:(NSString *)url
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadWorker:) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:url];
}

- (void)imageLoaded:(UIImage *)image
{
    // get the image into the UI
}
```

Call `downloadImageOnThread` for every image you want to load, each will get its own thread, and you'll get calls to `imageLoaded` as each one completes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure what you mean or how I can do it.  Could you explain a little further?

Comment: @pureman, did you see the link?  It's pretty straightforward - you use `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector...]` to create a thread with a specific method, and then use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to call back to the app when the worker thread is done.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  The code you provided worked great and I'm starting to grasp the concept.  Many thanks, once again.

Answer (score 3):

While loading the image on a background thread is definately the solution, I'd use an [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and an [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperationQueue) instead of dealing with the threads yourself (this is the way Apple recommend to deal with threading problems like this!)

The NSOperationQueue will deal with starting/stopping the threads nicely and you can choose how many to run at once etc. It's basically a the same as the other answers but you get a little more control.

There's a [tutorial here](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html) that looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

yeah you can use a secondary thread, and do a lot of work OR you could use things that apple gives us.

NSURLDownload, doesn't "lag" your main thread, You spawn it with a method and you set a endSelector, the endSelector will get called when the download is done.
Spawning a secondary thread for this is not really what you should do.

here you got some code from my app wich does it work perfectly without giving a beach ball of doom.

```
- (void)downloadAvatar:(NSString *)URL{
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URL];
 NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
 [url release];
 NSURLDownload *download = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@data/%@.jpg",[[BFAppSupport defaultSupport] bfFolderPath],[[xfSession loginIdentity] userName]];
 [download setDestination:path allowOverwrite:YES];
 [download release];
 [path release];
 [request release];
}
- (void)downloadDidFinish:(NSURLDownload *)download{
 NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@data/%@.jpg",[[BFAppSupport   defaultSupport] bfFolderPath],[[xfSession loginIdentity] userName]];
 NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if( [imageData length] < 10 ){
  [self performSelector:@selector(downloadAvatar:) withObject:@"http://media.xfire.com/xfire/xf/images/avatars/gallery/default/xfire160.jpg" afterDelay:0.0];
  [imageData release];
  [path release];
  return;
}
NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[imageData release];
[path release];
[yourImage setImage:theImage];
[theImage release];
}

- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)aDownload didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
 NSLog(@"Avatar url download failed");
}
```

The code is a bit ugly, but its not hard to change it as you got the 3 things you need, the method that starts the download and 2 that handle or an error or the finish.
You can also use autoreleased objects some more, but in terms of performance I like using it without autoreleased objects when I can.